# haproxy per backend ciphers/cipher suites

Tags: proxy, haproxy

I think the answer to this is no, but don’t understand why this feature is not available, I’d like to configure a list of ciphers on a per backend basis i.e to be able to use ssl-default-server-ciphers in each backend section rather than having to use ciphers on each server line. I don’t want to use ssl-default-server-ciphers in the global section as each backend can have a different set of ciphers.

I can't seem to add formatted text in comment reply, so I'll address  the response below by clarifying the question here. Backends DO have an option to specify ciphers, here is an edited example from one of my configs:

```
backend https_be
  server 10.255.2.5 10.255.2.5:443 ssl ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
  server 10.255.2.6 10.255.2.6:443 ssl ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

What I'd like to be able to do, and would be much cleaner is:

```
backend https_be
  option ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
  server 10.255.2.5 10.255.2.5:443 ssl  
  server 10.255.2.6 10.255.2.6:443 ssl
```

But haproxy does not seem to support this, I don't know why, it would be a useful think to do AND make config files easier to read. As for the comment on frontend reference I did not mention frontends so a little confused over that comment. It is true the same issue applies to bind on frontend, but I tried to keep it simple and illustrate the point with a backend example.

Answer (score 0):

> I’d like to configure a list of ciphers on a per backend basis

A backend have no cipher option. Do you mean the [bind](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#4-bind) option [ciphers](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#5.1-ciphers) ?

> I don’t want to use ssl-default-server-ciphers in the global section as each backend can have a different set of ciphers.

Well then don't set `ssl-default-server-ciphers` and define the ciphers on the server line.
A backend have servers which have [ciphers](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#5.2-ciphers) as option. Please don't mix the keywords with what you want to do.

frontend and listen => have bind option
backend have no bind option and therefore no [ciphers](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#5.1-ciphers) parameter!

This is explained in the [Proxies](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#4) section of the documentation.

Comment: Okay. The updated question is no better understandable. You are right the option `ssl-default-server-ciphers` is a global option for now. you can raise a Request for Enhancement (RFE) on GH https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues to maybe add this as an be option

Comment: "The updated question is no better understandable" I think you mean "the updated question is no clearer". In any case I don't know how I could make it more  perspicuous. I will file an RFE.

Comment: I found the RFE from @Bren if anyone sees this later. https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/1192